# Excel Doc macro yields "Named argument not found (Error 448)"

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This code snippet runs perfectly fine in Excel on Windows.
But on OSX, it's giving an error `Named argument not found (Error 448).`

```
With Sheets("Colors")
        Set rangeFound = .Cells.find(What:=Resource, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac does not support the SearchFormat argument. Just omit and the code will run.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.